# Convergence of Cauchy sample mean

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_i$'s are iid Cauchy random variables, does the sample mean $\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i}{n}$ converge in distribution to any limit? If yes, can someone explain to me how the limit can be computed step by step? I don't think it would, since the variance of a Cauchy random variable is infinity, but I am not so sure about this.

Comment: related - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $n$ $\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ also has the Cauchy distribution (!) so the Cauchy means certainly converge in distribution to the Cauchy distribution. The easiest way to prove this is to use characteristic functions: $Ee^{it \frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i}=(Ee^{itX_1/n})^{n}=(e^{-|t/n|})^{n}=e^{-|t|}$.

For the additional question in the comment below I will give a hint: If $S_n =\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ converges in probability then $S_{2n}-S_n \to 0$ in probability, hence in distribution. So its characteristic function must tend to $1$ at every point. But the characteristic function converges to $e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer. Does the Cauchy sample mean converge in probability to any limit as well? If you don't mind, could you include this also in your answer? THa nk you,

Comment: @chico0913 I have proved that it does not converge in probability.

Comment: Thank you very much