Question: Does the empirical mean of i.i.d. Cauchy random variables converge to a Cauchy distribution?
Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, each following the standard Cauchy distribution. Define the sequence of empirical means as:
$$
Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.
$$
I want to understand whether $Y_n$ converges in probability to the standard Cauchy distribution. It is well-known that the standard Cauchy distribution has no finite mean or variance, so the standard forms of the Law of Large Numbers do not apply. Despite this, it is known that $Y_n$ remains distributed according to the standard Cauchy distribution for all $n$, meaning the sequence trivially converges in distribution to the standard Cauchy law.
Intuitively, I would argue that $Y_n$ does not converge in probability, as I cannot think of a specific value that $Y_n$ would approach. Can someone provide a more rigorous explanation of why this is the case?
This problem comes from Chapter 18 of Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter, and I would appreciate an explanation or references to formal proofs.

As you said, $Y_n$ is also standard Cauchy distributed for all $n$. What else do you want as a proof that $Y_n$ does not converge in probability to some value? (Honestly asking, maybe I am missing something)

@Red, yes, I would like a rigorous argument on why the sequence $Y_n$ does not convergence in probability.

Read the second part of the answer to this question.

Got it, I answered the question. The missing detail was choosing an auxiliary sequence $Y_{2n} - Y_n,$ and rewriting the characteristic functions of this sequence remembering that the standard Cauchy has an even density!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238255/2546

$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb P}\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb E}$I'll elaborate a bit on the second part of this answer. To show that $Y_n$ doesn't converge in probability, suppose by contradiction that $Y_n\overset{\P}{\to}Y$ for some $Y$. Since $Y_{2n}$ is a subsequence, we also have $Y_{2n}\overset{\P}{\to}Y$. Thus, we also get that $Z_n:=Y_{2n}-Y_n\overset{\P}{\to}Y-Y=0$. Since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, we have that $Z_n\overset{\mathrm{d}}{\to}0$. Consequently, the characteristic function $\varphi_{\,\!_{Z_n}}$
must converge to $1$ pointwise. We have
\begin{align}
\varphi_{\,\!_{Z_n}\!}(\xi) &= \E\left[e^{ \xi i Z_{n}}\right]=\E\left[e^{ \xi i\left(Y_{2n}-Y_n\right)}\right] \\&= \E\left[  \exp\left(  \xi i\left(  \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{2 n}X_j - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right) \right) \right]\\&=\E
\left[  \exp\left( \frac{\xi}{2}\,i\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{2 n}X_j - 2 \, \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right) \right) \right] \\&=\E
\left[  \exp\left( \frac{\xi}{2}\,i\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2 n}X_j - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right) \right) \right]  \\&=\E
\left[  \exp\left( \frac{\xi}{2}\,i\, \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2 n}X_j\right)\exp\left( -\frac{\xi}{2}\,i \,\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right)  \right]  \\&=\E
\left[  \exp\left( \frac{\xi}{2}\,i\, \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2 n}X_j\right)\right]\E
\left[   \exp\left( -\frac{\xi}{2}\,i \,\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right)  \right]\end{align}
In the last equality we used the fact that the random variables $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2 n}X_j$ and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ are independent. Note that they are also $\mathrm{Cauchy}$ distributed, thus their characteristic function is $\varphi(\xi)=e^{-|\xi|}$. Hence, we get
\begin{align}
\varphi_{\,\!_{Z_n}\!}(\xi) &= \E
\left[  \exp\left( \frac{\xi}{2}\,i\, \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2 n}X_j\right)\right]\E
\left[   \exp\left( -\frac{\xi}{2}\,i \,\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right)  \right]\\&=\varphi\left(\frac{\xi}{2}\right)\,\varphi\left(-\frac{\xi}{2}\right) \\&= \exp\left(-\frac12|\xi|\right)\exp\left(-\frac12|\xi|\right)=\exp\left(-|\xi|\right)\not\to1, \end{align}
a contradiction.

One checks that for a standard Cauchy random variable, the characteristic formula equals
\begin{equation}
\phi_X(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-|t|}
\end{equation}
and given that $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is i.i.d., defining $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ yields
\begin{equation}
\phi_{Y_n/n}(t)=\phi_{X_1+\cdots+X_n}(t/n)=\mathrm{e}^{-|t|}
\end{equation}
as $\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)$ for any two independent random variables $X,Y$.
Now $\phi_{Y_n/n}(t)=\exp(-|t|)$, hence $Y_n/n$ is Cauchy distributed for all $n\geq 1$, and in particular $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n/n$.

(+1), but this answer establishes convergence in distribution of $Y_n/n$, not that of $Y_n/n$ itself (i.e. the existence of $\lim_nY_n/n$)

@Snoop as $Y_n/n$ converges weakly, it is not well defined to ask the question of what $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n/n$ is, given that it is random (and non-trivial). Am i understanding your point correctly?

Not really. You can refer to @framago's comment and answer

@Snoop, I see, thank you!

Yes, a linear combination of i.i.d. Cauchy random variables is also a Cauchy random variable. This is a special case of (alpha-) Stable distributions with $\alpha = 1$ corresponding to a Cauchy random variable.
Furthermore, the Generalized Central Limit Theorem (GCLT) applies to these distributional types of variables, which do not have a variance for $\alpha < 2$ and do not have a finite mean for $\alpha \leq 1$.
The name "stable", implies that their linear combinations belong to the same distribution types, which is somewhat surprising (to me) -- see much more info and references on that page.
Regarding semantics: As you state, it is well-known that the standard Cauchy distribution has no finite mean, so in my humble opinion, a better term instead of "the empirical mean" from the title (which could sound misleading), would probably be "a linear combination with equal weights", but this is just semantics.
Note: I hesitate to add the tag [central-limit-theorem] to the existing list of tags in this question, since the generalized version in my answer might confuse casual observers who are accustomed to the CLT applying to random variables with finite variance, unlike Cauchy and other $\alpha$-Stable distributions.

Apologies if my question was unclear earlier. Additionally, I had not noticed the discussion in the comments of one of the posts on this topic, which actually answers my query.
To clarify things further, I will reformulate Kavi Rama Murthy's answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901345/convergence-of-cauchy-sample-mean/3901355#3901355, elaborating on all the points that emerged.
If $Y_n$ converged in probability to a Cauchy distribution then $Z_n := Y_{2n} -Y_n$ would have to converge to $0$ in probability, hence in distribution. Consequently, the characteristic functions $\varphi_{Z_n}$  would have to converge to $1.$ But,
\begin{gather*}
\varphi_{Z_n}(\xi) = E\left[e^{i \cdot Z_{n} \cdot \xi }\right] = E\left[  \exp\left( \xi \cdot i \cdot \left(  \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{j=1}^{2\cdot n}X_j - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right) \right) \right]\\
E\left[  \exp\left( \dfrac{\xi \cdot i}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{2\cdot n}X_j - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j \right) \right) \right] = E\left[  \exp\left( \dfrac{\xi \cdot i}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2\cdot n}X_j + \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} - X_j \right) \right) \right] \\
= E\left[  \exp\left( \dfrac{\xi \cdot i}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=n+1}^{2\cdot n}X_j + \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  X_j \right) \right) \right] = E[i \cdot \xi \cdot Y_{n}] = exp(\vert - \xi \vert).
\end{gather*}
The second-to-last equality follows from the symmetry of the standard Cauchy distribution, while the penultimate step involves regrouping the sums and rearranging the multiplicative factors and applying the definition of $Y_n$.

You should use independence instead of symmetry.  I'll post an answer to show you.

You can't flip signs inside expectations just because of symmetry. For example, if $X$ is Cauchy distributed you have $\mathbb E(X+X)\neq\mathbb E(X-X)$. In fact, the LHS is undefined, while the RHS is $0$.

@framago, thank you for your feedback! I initially wanted to use the independence of random variables to split the product and take it a step further, but I didn't follow through out of laziness. Now I see for sure that it's incorrect. Would it be alright if I left my answer as is and marked yours as the correct one?

Sure, always glad to help :^)
